# Length function in python is not working the way I want to

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbie to programming and python. I looked online for help and I doing as they say but I think I am making a mistake which I am not able to catch. 
For now all I'm trying to do here is: if the word matches the length that user entered with the word in the file, make a list of those words. It sort of works if I replace `userLength` with the actual number but it's not working with variable `userlength`. I need that list later to develop Hangman.

Any help or recommendation on code will be great.

```
def welcome():
    print("Welcome to the Hangman: ")
    userLength = input ("Please tell us how long word you want to play : ")
    print(userLength)

    text = open("test.txt").read()
    counts = Counter([len(word.strip('?!,.')) for word in text.split()])
    counts[10]
    print(counts)
    for wl in text.split():

        if len(wl) == counts :
            wordLen = len(text.split())
            print (wordLen)
            print(wl)

    filename = open("test.txt")
    lines = filename.readlines()
    filename.close()
    print (lines)
    for line in lines:
        wl = len(line)
        print (wl)

        if wl == userLength:

            words = line
            print (words)

def main ():
    welcome()

main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input()` returns a string py3.x , so you must convert it to `int` first.

```
userLength = int(input ("Please tell us how long word you want to play : "))
```

And instead of using `readlines` you can iterate over one line at once, it is memory efficient. Secondly use the `with` statement when handling files as it automatically closes the file for you.:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:         #fetches  a single line each time
       line = line.strip() #remove newline or other whitespace charcters
       wl = len(line)
       print (wl)
       if wl == userLength:
         words = line
         print (words)
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) function returns a string, so you need to turn `userLength` into an `int`, like this:

```
userLength = int(userLength)
```

As it is, the line `wl == userLength` is always `False`.

---

**Re: comment**

Here's one way to build that word list of words with the correct length:

```
def welcome():
    print("Welcome to the Hangman: ")
    userLength = int(input("Please tell us how long word you want to play : "))

    words = []
    with open("test.txt") as lines:
        for line in lines:
            word = line.strip()
            if len(word) == userLength:
                words.append(word)
```

Comment: Make sense. I was printing the userLength it was printing the length so I was not sure. Would you be able to tell me how can I create a list. 'Words' is suppose to be a list but its just giving me a single word at a time.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AAA You already have a list of the words in the variable `lines`, though each word ends with a linefeed. To remove them, do `lines = [word.strip() for word in lines]`.

Comment: As it was recommended by Ashwini, I changed that part of the code to

with open("test.txt") as f:
    #lines = filename.readlines()
    #filename.close()
    #print (lines)
        for line in f:
            line = [word.strip() for word in line]
            wl = len(line)
            print (wl)
       
            if wl == userLength:
                words = line
                print (words)

Comment: so now its doing something different. Its still not creating the list.